# How to change colour of MGLFILLExtrusionStyleLayer in mapbox in objective c

Tags: objective-c, mapbox

I am new in iPhone applications development. I have faced one issue in drawing layer using MGLFILLExtrusionStyleLayer. I haven't change layer colour. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of a `MGLFillExtrustionLayer` by setting the [`fillExtrusionColor`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.7.0-beta.3/Classes/MGLFillExtrusionStyleLayer.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLFillExtrusionStyleLayer(py)fillExtrusionColor) property.

For example:

```
 let layer = MGLFillExtrusionStyleLayer(identifier: "fill-extrusion-layer", source: source)
 layer.fillExtrusionColor = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: .purple)
 style.addLayer(layer)
```

You may find [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/extrusions/) helpful.